# Set background color with color from UI Text Field input

Tags: swift, input, colors, background, uitextfield

I'm brand new to swift and am trying to set my background color the color input by a user into a UI Text Field. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What input is expected? For example “00AEEF” or “light-blue”?

Comment: @aheze Red or Green

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest listening to [`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) methods instead of adding a target for `textFieldDidChange`, which is called whenever the text inside the text field changes (even when just adding a single character).

The [`textFieldShouldReturn(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn) delegate method seems right for your purpose — this gets called when the <kbd>Return</kbd> key is pressed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        textField.delegate = self /// set the delegate
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    /// one of many UITextField delegate methods: see here for more https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        
        switch textField.text?.lowercased() {
        case "red":
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        case "green":
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        default:
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white /// default if entered text was not Red or Green
        }
        
        return true /// allow the return button to be pressed
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Background color of entire screen changes when Red or Green is entered in the text field]

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to changes in the textField by adding the following code to your ViewController's viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
//Subscribe to changes in the textField
textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
}
```

You can get the UITextField's name using `textField.text`, and pass that into the initializer for a UIColor, and use that to set the color of the view's background, like so:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

  if let text = textField.text{
   self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: text) ?? UIColor(named: "white")
    }
}
```